# npm - Semver versioning - Updating a package with a caret "^"

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning, npm-update

I have a npm package in my package.json file

```
 "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.18"
```

Now when I hover over the package I can see that there is a newer version

```
"clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19"
```

Now, as I understood, I could for example do `npm update` to update all packages obeying the semver rules or just the package `npm update clean-webpack-plugin`.

So the caret `^` symbol should mean, that you could possibly update the packge to version `0.9.9` if available, right?

`npm update` has no effect, that's why I ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm quite certain that npm will have updated the application files for `clean-webpack-plugin` *from* version `0.1.18` *to* version `0.1.19` after you run: `npm update clean-webpack-plugin` as described in your question.

However, npm will not have updated the entry in your `package.json` as theoretically it's not actually necessary to do so. Why?.. because version `"^0.1.18"` is specified in `package.json`. I.e. The version is specified with the caret `^` symbol.

Let's say your were to publish your project with `^0.1.18` specified in `package.json` then any subsequent user running `npm install` will actually get version `0.1.19` anyway *(caveat: as the version history for `clean-webpack-plugin` currently stands in the npm repository at the time of writing this)*.

So, in short I'm quite sure that version `0.1.19` has been installed on your system, it simply hasn't changed the version specified in `package.json`. It's not actually necessary to do so and the rules of semver and the use of the caret symbol are still being respected.

> So the caret `^` symbol should mean, that you could possibly update the package to version `0.9.9` if available, right?

The caret in `"^0.1.18"` is saying to npm I WILL accept any updates to the most recent [MINOR](https://semver.org/) version but I WILL NOT accept a MAJOR update. I.e. `^0.1.18` means any updates in the range `>=0.1.18 <1.0.0` *(PATCH updates within that range are allowed too)*.

---

**Verifying whether it has been updated:**

To verify whether version `0.1.19` has actually been installed you can `cd` to your project directory and run:

```js
npm ls clean-webpack-plugin
```

You should see the following logged to your console:

```
...
└── clean-webpack-plugin@0.1.19
```

---

**But I want `package.json` to show `"^0.1.19"` after running `npm update`:**

When you initially run `npm update clean-webpack-plugin` you could have:

1. Appended the `--save-dev` argument *(applicable if it was listed in your `devDependencies` section of `package.json`)*.
2. Or, appended the `--save` argument *(applicable if it was listed in your `dependencies` section of `package.json`)*.

Appending either `--save-dev` or `--save` as appropriate to `npm update clean-webpack-plugin` would have update the entry in `package.json`. This is further explained in the [Recording Updates with `--save`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update#recording-updates-with---save) section of the npm documentation.

By doing this, you can think of it as re-specifying the initial `>=` part of the range of updates you'll accept.

---

**Note**

Running `npm update clean-webpack-plugin` with the additional `--save` or `--save-dev` argument will not have any affect if `npm ls clean-webpack-plugin` reports:

```
...
└── clean-webpack-plugin@0.1.19
```

There would be nothing to update, so I'd just manually specify `"^0.1.19"` in `package.json`.

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks for the detailed explanation !