# semver notation doesn't update patch/minor version

Tags: node.js, npm

semver notation(~, ^) doesn't update patch/minor version of any package while `npm install` or `npm update` with npm@5.
scenarios noticed :

1. if I install package by updating minor version through CLI it
   updates    in package.json and npm-shrinkwrap.json.
2. `npm install ember-ajax@3.1.1` - Works in CLI and updates files.
3. `npm install ember-ajax@~3.1.0` - Doesn't install ember-ajax@3.1.1 through CLI.
4. updating in package.json like `ember-ajax: "~3.1.0"` and do `npm install` - Doesn't update the patch version.

I am not sure what I have missed to udpate this.
[Tried this didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270776/npm-semver-versioning-updating-a-package-with-a-caret)