# Npm update wont modify package.json

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-update

Lets imagine i have a npm dependency as this: "webpack": "^5.24.4"

Lets imagine that a new 5.30.0 version is released, so i do a npm update. Webpack is updated, but the package.json stays the same, even whit --save or --save-dev

This is the expected behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm - Semver versioning - Updating a package with a caret "^"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270776/npm-semver-versioning-updating-a-package-with-a-caret)

Comment: @RobC thas what im thinking, but --save or --save-dev has no effect.Maybe too new npm?? (v7)

Comment: I force a install of an older version (still beging whit ^5.) and then try the update whit save or --save-dev, but no luck

Answer (score 4):

Feature to semver update package.json was removed in npm v7 https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2704

And returned back in v8.3.2 https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-update

To update dependencies in package.json and maintain semantic versions:

```
npm update --save
```